# What is the equivalent to shift drag for scaling in gimp?

Tags: gimp

If I want to resize a layer in photoshop I cmd+T, hold down Shift and drag a corner so it doesn't skew it in the process of resizing. How do I accomplish the same thing on GIMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the Scale tool. If you hover the cursor over it, it advertises to operate also with layers.

- zoom out the image to be smaller than your screen
- select the layer
- drag by the Scale tool the corner holding Ctrl at the same time

You must accept the resizing in the dialog that opens without asking.

NOTE: if you do not drag, only click, you get the same dialog. You can enter for example: link x and y, new size = 50%

Comment: It's called the Scale tool: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Shift + S, It will activate the scale tool.
Similarly, you can activate the rotate toll using Shift + R